# Maximum diameter of circle inscribed by the intersection of 3 other circles

Tags: geometry, circles

I would like to calculate the maximum diameter of a circle that is inscribed by the intersection of 3 other circles. The 3 circles have known diameters and center point coordinates. [See illustration here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YSzw.png)

[image]

Where the red, green, and blue circles are given and the black is to be calculated.

It may also be the case that the inscribed circle is tangent to only two of the circles as shown [in this illustration.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Dqte.png)

[image]

Is this already a known mathematical example with a name that I can look up? How would I approach solving this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Dillon

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_center. In some cases, you can probably approximate the region and get a LP, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953623/is-there-a-simple-algorithm-for-calculating-the-maximum-inscribed-circle-into-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with 
inscribing circle into
the intersection of two circles:

[image]

and the use this configuration as a building block.

For given intersection of two circles 
$\bigcirc(A,r_a)$ and 
$\bigcirc(B,r_b)$, 
$|AB|=d$,
the maximal radius of the inscribed circle

\begin{align} 
r_{\max}&=\tfrac12\,(r_a+r_b-d)
.
\end{align}

Considering $A$ at the origin, 
the coordinates of the center $O$ 
of inscribed circle 
$\bigcirc(O,r)$

\begin{align} 
O_x&=
d-\frac{(r_b-r)\Big(d^2+(r_b-r)^2-(r_a-r)^2\Big)}{2d(r_b-r)}
,\\
O_y&=
(r_b-r)\sqrt{1-\Big(\frac{d^2+(r_b-r)^2-(r_a-r)^2}{2d(r_b-r)}\Big)^2}
.
\end{align}

The blue line on the diagram represents the locus 
of the centers of all possible inscribed circles.

Similarly, the other pair of circles,
say, $\bigcirc(B,r_b)$ and $\bigcirc(C,r_c)$
can be added to the diagram (with proper rotation),
and the intersection of the loci curves
will give a center of the circle,
inscribed in the intersection of all the three circles,
 $\bigcirc(A,r_a),\,\bigcirc(B,r_b)$ and $\bigcirc(C,r_c)$.

For example, like this:

[image]

Comment: Impressive work! I haven't had a chance to code this up in MATLAB to verify, but it seems like this is exactly what I need. I'll test it out as soon as possible and reply with the results.